# Keep text in place while replacing one element with another

Tags: beamer, animations

I am trying to have the image in \only<2> replace the text in \only<3> without having the text in \visible<1,2,3> bounce around. How do I accomplish this?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\visible<1,2,3>{Blalalalalalala}

\only<2>{
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{pic1.png}
\end{figure}}

\only<3>{Balalalalala}}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Does `\begin{frame}[t]` solve your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an `overlayarea`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{test}
    \visible<1,2,3>{Blalalalalalala}

    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.5\textheight}
        \only<2>{
        \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
        \end{figure}}

        \only<3>{Balalalalala}
    \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

---

off-topic:

- floating specifier like `[!htb]` don't make sense in a documentclass that does not have a floating mechanism
- you don't need `\centering` in the figure, beamer automatically centres figures
- in case there are only the 3 overlays you show use, you don't need `\visible<1,2,3>{Blalalalalalala}`, simply replace it by `Blalalalalalala`. If there are more overlays after these, you can simplify it by using `\visible<1-3>{...}`